# Unix: what modifier key does "M-" refer to (e.g. M-C)

Tags: unix, nano

I'm trying to do a case-sensitive search in Nano.  The help menu at the bottom of the screen says I can toggle case-sensitivity by typing `M-C`.

```
^G Get Help         ^Y First Line       ^T Go To Line       ^W Beg of Par       M-J FullJstify      M-B Backwards
^C Cancel           ^V Last Line        ^R Replace          ^O End of Par       M-C Case Sens       M-R Regexp
```

I'm not sure how to do this.  Does `M-` refer to a modifier key that should be held while I type `C`?  Or does `M-` mean I should press some key or key combination before hitting `C`?

Comment: I notice that I'm getting close votes. Would this question be more appropriate for unix.stackexchange.com? Should I delete this and repost there?

Comment: Probably superuser.com would be best. Technically, it depends on the terminal emulator you are using.

Comment: Alright. If it gets closed I'll throw it up on superuser.

Comment: Once upon a time there was a thing called a Lisp machine. It was very much pertinent to programming, but today it gets a downvote and ignored. 

"Most of the people who do what we do are not aware of where this stuff came from, not aware of their own craft. We have no sense of history, really, in software. Part of that is because it turns over so quickly, but part of it is that we’ve forgotten all this important knowledge." - Douglas Crockford on HanselMinutes. 

http://hanselminutes.com/396/bugs-considered-harmful-with-douglas-crockford

Answer (score 128, accepted):

`M` refers to the meta key, which is not present on most keyboards. (Its use in software is for primarily historical reasons.) Usually, the meta key is emulated by another key on your keyboard. On Windows and Linux, it is usually the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. On Mac OS X, that key (aka <kbd>Option</kbd>) already has other uses, and so <kbd>Escape</kbd> is used instead.

Comment: Well, escape followed by C, but yes :)

Comment: I'm trying `M-?` combination in midnight commander on Ubuntu 16. But when I press `Alt`, the Ubuntu menu in the top of the screen activates. So the combination doesn't work: MC doesn't start a file search which the combination stands for.

Comment: Got it: in this specific case I had to press "Shift" too.

Comment: Right; it all depends on what you need in order for the terminal emulator to send the correct "keys" on to the program it is running.

Comment: @serge when using graphical terminal, it will most likely capture the `ALT` key for its own shortcuts. `SHIFT` sometimes helps, but not always. The only consistent workaround is to use `ESC` for the meta key.

Comment: This helped me toggle backwards search in nano. Thank you! It was indeed the `ESC` key. How unintuitive... Suppose they ran out of options.

Comment: on a mac, the proper sequence is:
<esc> c
not:
<esc> m c

Answer (score 8):

I do not know for `nano`, but for `emacs`, `M-` stands for the **Meta key**, which can mean pressing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key simultaneously with the letter key or by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> key before the letter key. <kbd>Alt</kbd> generally only works when using an X version of the application, so when using a dumb terminal, only <kbd>Esc</kbd> will work.

Answer (score 7):

Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to give nano a command.

For instance, if you wanted to tell nano to move the cursor to the end of the file, you'd press

<kbd>Esc</kbd> then <kbd>/</kbd>

You don't need to hold down <kbd>Esc</kbd> as if it were <kbd>Shift</kbd>.